# Annotation Processor, modifying the annotated class

Tags: java, annotations

I went through various tutorials and finally successfully create my annotation but I'm struggling with the implementation of it.

What I had in mind is as follows:

1. Annotate a class
2. Annotation Processor generate a backup class with some boiler plate code.
3. Make the annotated class extend the backup class so users can override methods if needed.

I was successful with 1 and 2 but not sure if 3 is the way to go. I want to do something like @WebService where a lot of code is generated in the background but the user can still use the annotated class to do coding.

Any idea os more than welcomed. I'll start looking at the @WebService meanwhile but I suspect it to be way too complicated.

**Edit**: If needed the source for the annotation and processors can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/jwrestling/src).

Comment: Is there a source code available to your generated annotation?

Comment: What do you mean by generated annotation? An example of the result of running the AnnotationProcessor on an annotated class?

Comment: isn't dynamic proxy a better choice for your number 3?

Comment: Might be, I just don't know anything about those 2 options. Please enlighten me with an example on how those might help.

Comment: From the Dynamic Proxy documentation it seems that might do the trick. Let's see if I find a tutorial for it.